# buscar un numero en una matriz usando búsqueda binaria

Tags: java

Tengo una matriz ordenada, quiero saber si de encuentra un valor dentro de ella usando la búsqueda binaria.

El problema es que no se como hallar el valor central de la matriz para iniciar el ciclo, he visto el algoritmo en un array uni pero cómo paso esa lógica a uno bidimensional.

Hasta hora he hecho esto, ordeno la matriz y un código comentando sin lógica que habia hecho.

```
    public int busquedaBinaria(int numero) {

    int mayor, pos;
    for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<matriz[i].length; j++) {
            for(int x= 0; x<matriz.length; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                    if(matriz[i][j]<matriz[x][y]) {
                    mayor = matriz[i][j];
                    matriz[i][j]= matriz[x][y];
                    matriz[x][y]= mayor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    // while (primero <= ultimo) {
    // centro = (primero + ultimo) / 2;
    // if (matriz[centro][centro] == numero) {
    // return centro;
    // } else if (numero < matriz[centro][centro]) {
    // primero = centro - 1;
    //
    // } else {
    // ultimo = centro + 1;
    // }
    // }

    return -1;
}
```

Una mano, gracias.

Comment: para el centro de una matriz :  x = round(matrizX.length /2 ) y para y = round(matrizY.length /2)  no entiendo tu pregunta pero recorres muchas veces algo que no creo que deba ser asi

Comment: los for anidados son para ordenar los números que contienen la matriz. En si la pregunta es cómo aplicar la búsqueda binaria en un array bidimensional.

Comment: una matriz es un vector agrupado por filas, por lo tanto si tienes una matriz de `A[i][j]` tienes un vector de tamaño `i*j`. Ahora en busqueda binaria se encuentra la mitad del vector es decir `mitad = i * j / 2`, ese número que nos da lo convertimos en una posición `[i'][j']` de la matriz con la siguiente formula `j' =  mitad / j` y la fila se optiene `i' = mitad % j`

Comment: @isaac ten cuidado con matrices que devuelven un numero no par ej (matriz 3 * 5 = 15 / 2 )

Comment: @JackNavaRow, en tu ejemplo la respuesta sería 7.5, sin embargo esta no se almacena en un tipo de dato decimal (float o double) si no en un entero por lo cual solo toma la parte entera que sería 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este caso de búsqueda binaria requiere de un análisis cuidadoso. No hay una respuesta única que sea la correcta, sin embargo muchas "soluciones" pueden dar problemas al variar la matriz de entrada. Así que antes de proponer una respuesta vamos a examinar por qué las soluciones propuestas en los comentarios pueden fallar.

> Primer caso

```
x = round(matrizX.length /2 )
y = round(matrizY.length /2)
```

Supongamos una matriz de 10x2 con el valor a buscar 110, el cual se encuentra en la posición x = 1 , y = 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la primera iteración, obtenemos las coordenadas de la mitad así:

```
x = round(10/2) = 5
y = round/2/2) = 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto nos da el primer problema: la mitad debería haber sido la posición (10,1), y no (5,1). Esto implica **mas iteraciones**, pues como el valor buscado es superior a la mitad (110 > 50), apenas discriminamos los primeros cuatro valores (en la búsqueda binaria, se va discriminando mitad a mitad, siendo muy eficiente). Y en la siguiente iteración, ¿de que tamaño es la matriz que nos queda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo determinamos de que tamaño es x y y? Podríamos volver a meter los datos en una nueva matriz (y en ese caso, ¿de que tamaño?), pero luego en la siguiente iteración nos veremos obligados a realizar lo mismo. Demasiados problemas y no es eficiente.

> Segundo caso

```
mitad = i * j / 2
j' = mitad / j
i' = mitad % j
```

Para la misma matriz, esto nos daría los siguientes cálculos:

```
mitad = 10 * 2 /2 = 10
j' = 10/2 = 5
i' = 10%2= 0
```

Así que nuestra mitad se encuentra en la posición i',j' que sería (0,5). Pero esa **posición no existe** en nuestra matriz. Desde este punto, ni siquiera podemos comenzar a iterar.

Entonces, ¿cuál puede ser una solución en la que no importe el número de filas y columnas que tenga la matriz? Bueno, podemos intentar una solución con una de las herramientas más maravillosas que utilizamos en la programación: la **abstracción**.

> Propuesta de solución

Tu mismo indicas que ya has visto el algoritmo de la búsqueda binaria para un vector unidimensional. Entonces vamos a abstraer la complejidad de la matriz y vamos a representarla mediante un vector unidimensional. Vamos a manejar una matriz de posiciones en la que vamos a mapear las posiciones asociandolas con las coordenadas de la matriz de entrada, donde Y será el número de posiciones total, y X será 3: una columna para la posición, otra columna para el valor de X, y la tercera columna tendrá el valor de Y. Nuestra primera columna (la de posiciones) será la que utilizaremos para realizar la búsqueda binaria.

Para la misma matriz, la matriz de posiciones quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y trabajaríamos la búsqueda binaria, únicamente utilizando la primera columna, la de las posiciones. La diferencia es que necesitariamos un método que dada la posición, nos devuelva el valor de dicha posición y luego compararlo contra el valor buscado.

```
private int DevolverValorDeLaPosicion(int mitad, int[][] matrizPosiciones, int[][] matrizEntrada)
{           
     int coordenadaX = matrizPosiciones[2][mitad];
     int coordenadaY = matrizPosiciones[3][mitad];

     return matrizEntrada[coordenadaX][coordenadaY];
}
```

Las iteraciones quedarían así:

```
Valor buscado: 110
Límite inferior: 1
Límite superior: 20
Mitad = (1 + 20) /2 = 10

DevolverValorDeLaPosicion(Mitad, matrizPosiciones, matrizEntrada) = 100
```

- ¿110 == 100? No. Se deben volver a calcular los límites.
- ¿110<100?No. Se discrimina la mitad inferior.
- ¿110>100? Si. Se toma como nuevo límite inferior la posición de la
  mitad, que es 10.

Nueva iteración:

```
 Valor buscado: 110
 Límite inferior: 10
 Límite superior: 20
 Mitad = (10 + 20) /2 = 15

 DevolverValorDeLaPosicion(Mitad, matrizPosiciones, matrizEntrada) = 150
```

- ¿110 == 150? No. Se deben volver a calcular los límites.
- ¿110<150?Si. Se toma como nuevo límite superior la posición de la mitad, que es 15.
- ¿110>150? No. Se discrimina la mitad superior.

Siguiente iteración:

```
Valor buscado: 110
Límite inferior: 10
Límite superior: 15
Mitad = (10 + 15) /2 = 12

DevolverValorDeLaPosicion(Mitad, matrizPosiciones, matrizEntrada) = 120
```

- ¿110 == 120? No. Se deben volver a calcular los límites.
- ¿110<120?Si. Se toma como nuevo límite superior la posición de la mitad, que es 12.
- ¿110>120? No. Se discrimina la mitad superior.

Siguiente iteración:

```
 Valor buscado: 110
 Límite inferior: 10
 Límite superior: 12
 Mitad = (10 + 12) /2 = 11

 DevolverValorDeLaPosicion(Mitad, matrizPosiciones, matrizEntrada) = 110
```

- ¿110 == 110? Si!. Encontramos el valor.

Esta aproximación, nos permite incluso manejar mas dimensiones, buscar un valor en un cubo por ejemplo. La idea es siempre la misma, representar cada conjunto de coordenadas de la matriz como un solo valor.

¿Contras de esta propuesta? Necesitamos una matriz extra para el mapeo de posiciones, y llenarla con todas las posiciones de la matriz de entrada, luego de que esta sea ordenada. Sin embargo, esto solo se hace una vez. La llamada a la función que dada la posición devuelve el valor si debe llamarse en cada iteración.

> Apuntes finales en la implementación

- Antes de realizar la primera iteración, verificar siempre si el valor
  a buscar esta dentro de los límites iniciales. Lo peor sería realizar
  una búsqueda binaria de un valor que está afuera de los límites, pues
  sería inútil.
- Antes de realizar la primera iteración, y si el valor a buscar está
  dentro del rango de valores que maneja la matriz de entrada,
  verificar si el valor a buscar no corresponde a alguno de los
  límites. Otra mala situación sería tener que iterar hasta encontrar
  que alguno de los límites iniciales contenía el valor, por no haber
  verificado esto de antemano. Luego, como en cada iteración la mitad
  se toma como un nuevo límite (si es que no se encuentra el valor), ya
  no es necesario volver a realizar la comparación pues ya se sabe que
  el valor no corresponde a los límites.
- Tomar en cuenta que aunque el valor a buscar, este dentro del rango
  de los límites inferior y superior iniciales, puede ser que no exista
  en la matriz. Por ejemplo, en nuestra matriz de prueba imaginemos que
  buscamos el valor 117. Entonces se debe verificar bien cual va a ser
  la condición de salida del bucle, para no quedarnos en un ciclo
  infinito.
- Cuando se calcula la mitad (límite inferior + límite superior)/2,
  considerar que podemos salirnos del dominio del tipo de dato
  utilizado en la suma de los límites. Por ejemplo, supongamos que el tipo de dato int solo tiene
  un dominio de los números del 1 al 1000. Ahora supongamos que
  manejamos un matriz de 100 x 10, es decir, mil posiciones. En la
  primera iteración tendríamos:

Límite inferior = 1

Límite superior = 1000

int Mitad = (1+1000)/2

Pero aquí al realizar la suma de 1+1000 nos da 1001. Nos salimos del dominio!

Así que cuidado, muchas implementaciones pueden realizar desbordamientos en la suma de los límites, si se manejan vectores exageradamente grandes.

Answer (score 1):

Coincido con @JYass, la estrategia más directa es agregar una capa de abstracción, conociendo el número de filas y columnas de la matriz bidimensional podemos calcular directamente las coordenas que corresponderían a la posición en un vector.

```
def get_cords(index):
  return (index-1)//cols, (index-1)%cols
```

Implementé la siguiente función para verificar que el mapeo que produce la función **get_cords** es la correcta.

```
def check_mapping():
  for idx in range(1,size+1):
    i,j = get_cords(idx)
    print (idx,i,j,m[i][j])
```

Tabla de mapeo generada por la funcion **check_mapping**

```
| pos | i | j  | valor |
|-----|---|----|-------|
| 1   | 0 | 0  | 10    |
| 2   | 0 | 1  | 20    |
| 3   | 0 | 2  | 30    |
| 4   | 0 | 3  | 40    |
| 5   | 0 | 4  | 50    |
| 6   | 0 | 5  | 60    |
| 7   | 0 | 6  | 70    |
| 8   | 0 | 7  | 80    |
| 9   | 0 | 8  | 90    |
| 10  | 0 | 9  | 100   |
| 11  | 0 | 10 | 104   |
| 12  | 1 | 0  | 110   |
| 13  | 1 | 1  | 120   |
| 14  | 1 | 2  | 130   |
| 15  | 1 | 3  | 140   |
| 16  | 1 | 4  | 150   |
| 17  | 1 | 5  | 160   |
| 18  | 1 | 6  | 170   |
| 19  | 1 | 7  | 180   |
| 20  | 1 | 8  | 190   |
| 21  | 1 | 9  | 200   |
| 22  | 1 | 10 | 201   |
```

No pude hacer la implementación en Java, solo puedo contribuir con la implementación de la versión recursiva en [python3](/questions/tagged/python3).

**Nota**: // en python representa el operador de división entera.

```
import sys

m = [[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,104],[110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,201]]
rows = len(m)
cols = len(m[0])
size = rows * cols

def get_cords(index):
    return (index-1)//cols, (index-1)%cols

def binary_search(lower_bound, upper_bound, target):        
    if lower_bound > upper_bound:
        return False

    middle = (lower_bound+upper_bound)//2
    i,j = get_cords(middle)
    print (lower_bound, upper_bound,m[i][j])
    if m[i][j] == target:
        return True
    elif m[i][j] > target:
        return binary_search(lower_bound,middle-1,target)
    else:
        return binary_search(middle+1,upper_bound,target)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (binary_search(0,size,int(sys.argv[1])))
```